# Plotting Dataframe as a bar chart with each column on a separate y axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a Dataframe like this:

[image]

i would like to find a simple way of presenting this in a matplotlib bar chart, with the columns as a seperate yaxis.  As in the below sketch:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? If you are plotting two columns into the same bar chart, traditionally you'll want the column color go on a legend, not on the y axis. The y axis should denote the measurement unit.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Im new to data science and im curious excatly what you are meaning?

Comment: The plot Quang Hoang posted in the comments is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Use seaborn and use hue parameter:

```
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax =seaborn.barplot(
    data= df.melt(id_vars='index').rename(columns=str.title),
    x= 'index',
    y= 'value',
    hue='varaible'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'sum_prices':[100,200,300],
                  'properties':[10,5, 4]}, index=list('abc'))

df.plot.bar(secondary_y=['properties'])
```

output:

[image]